# Is there a PostGIS IDE to execute postgres gis spatial functions?

Tags: gis, postgis, geodjango

Is there a PostGIS IDE to execute postgres gis spatial functions?

samples sql

```
SELECT ST_Distance(gg1, gg2) As spheroid_dist, ST_Distance(gg1, gg2, false) As sphere_dist 
FROM (SELECT
    ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-72.1235 42.3521)') As gg1,
    ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(-72.1260 42.45, -72.123 42.1546)') As gg2
    ) As foo  ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an IDE but you could try using [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) with one of PostGIS plugins:

- [Fast-SQL-Layer](https://github.com/pablotcarreira/Fast-SQL-Layer)
- [PGQuery for QGIS](http://www.carteryx.com/) (go to downloads)
- [PostGIS Manager](https://github.com/wonder-sk/postgis_manager/)

Also, you might want to have a look at [Efficiently using QGIS with PostGIS](http://www.fosslc.org/drupal/content/efficiently-using-qgis-postgis) presentation from FOSS4G2011.

Comment: may i ask your preference between those options?

Comment: @eros: I personally tend to interact directly with PostgreSQL through SQL in pgAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy/paste the [WKB hex output](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) directly into *JTS TestBuilder* (part of [Java Topology Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/)) to get a visualization.

See [this related answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12105/gis-pros-what-free-programs-should-every-gis-user-have-installed/12119#12119).